# Multiple IF and ISBLANK in 1 Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Greeting

i have a problem with a formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AK20),""," - "&AK20&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM20&""),IF(ISBLANK(AK21),""," - "&AK21&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM21&"")
```

[image]

in counter a #VALUE Result.

Any idea how to fix it??

Thanks

Comment: Common error between two IF function. First if already completed and you start second if with comma with would be concatenate operator like `=IF(ISBLANK(AK20),""," - "&AK20&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM20&"") & IF(ISBLANK(AK21),""," - "&AK21&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM21&"")`

Comment: I have posted as answer. Please mark it as answered. Tick mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

Common error between two IF function. First if already completed and you start second if with comma with would be concatenate operator like

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AK20),""," - "&AK20&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM20&"") & IF(ISBLANK(AK21),""," - "&AK21&" "&K19&" "&O19&" = "&AM21&"")
```